# Change src with radio buttons

Tags: html, dom, checkbox, radio-button, src

On my project Im trying to change src with my radio buttons.`

As you see from my codes Im trying to change 4 src. "imghali" and "qrimage" is working on my project. When I check my buttons (birinci1 and birinci2) "imghali" and "qrimage" src is changing. but "arhali" src (ar-button's src) is not changing.

What is wrong here ? any solution or suggestion would be great.

[My Project Link](https://basebros.com/config-6.html)

```js
function Pris()
  {
  if ( document.getElementById("birinci1").checked 
    && document.getElementById ("ikinci1").checked )
    {
    document.getElementById("imghali").src   = "Hali/FinalResimler/hali1-80x200.png";
    document.getElementById("arhali").src    = "https://basebros.com/Hali/haliar/hali1-80x200.glb";
    document.getElementById("arhali").iosSrc = "Hali/haliar/hali1-80x200ios.usdz";
    document.getElementById("qrimage").src   = "Hali/qrcodes/haliqrsec1.png";
    }
  }
```

```html
<ar-button id="arhali"
   src="https://basebros.com/Hali/haliar/hali1-80x200.glb"
   ios-src="Hali/haliar/hali1-80x200ios.usdz"
   title="3D-AR by BASE">
 
 <img class="arbuttonicon"  src="Assets/roboticon.png" alt="AR-icon">

 </ar-button>
```

`

Comment: Why `.iosSrc = ""` ?

Comment: this is not html. witch frameWork Environement do you use ?

Comment: it is html. you can check from my project link.

Comment: .iosSrc cuz of different 3d model formats for ios and android. I mean this is Augmented Reality script and first src for android second one is for ios

Comment: there is no tag element `<ar-button>` in HTML. your code is not HTML  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

Comment: It is javascript from "https://unpkg.com/@leoncvlt/ar-button". I added this script to my html page.

Comment: didn't I ask you what environment you are using?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I didn't find the documentation of your package...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to attach images which has png or jpeg like format.

```
 document.getElementById("arhali").src    = "https://basebros.com/Hali/haliar/hali1-80x200.glb";
 document.getElementById("arhali").iosSrc = "Hali/haliar/hali1-80x200ios.usdz";
```

I think you should delete the one which has iosSrc and try replacing it with src and with a image which has a image format of jpeg or png anything similar

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what do you prefer.

Comment: Try replacing .iosSrc with .src and the link should be of image format(jpeg,png)

Comment: Yes I tried it now. But nothing change again. I think problem is we cant reach to id="arhali" which is ar-button's

Comment: try using  a normal button instead of it

Comment: I cant use normal button. Because it is javascript from "https://unpkg.com/@leoncvlt/ar-button" and ar-button is attribute of this script

Comment: oh sorry I don't know much from Ar script this and I might suggest to try adding a class and use DOM to get element that have the particular class